# Digitizing polygons against georeferenced map using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, digitizing

I am drawing polygons of counties over a 17th Century map that I have georeferenced. I have an issue with this version of ArcMap which I haven't experienced with past versions.

The shape keeps closing after 3 vertexes have been applied.  The only way I have found to get round this is to draw a square of vertexes over the whole county and then keep adding vertexes to draw in the polygon which is very time consuming.

How can I avoid this happening?

Comment: You don't state what version you're using, and the tag applies to both 10.4.0 and 10.4.1 (the latter of which should be the only version used at this late date, with the relevant security patches applied). Esri Tech Support is probably a better resource for this sort of question than GIS SE.

Comment: I’m happy to try and help you frame a question suitable for this site. My first edits will be to focus it to a single question then I’ll ask some things as comments that you can use to edit some more.

Comment: What coordinate system is your georeferenced map?  What coordinate system is the feature class that you are digitizing into?

Comment: May I suggest you to screenshot  it of what you are  doing ? That helps us to know what you are doing ?